# Spring Boot MVC/Rest controller and enum deserialization converter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

In my Spring Boot application I have a following `@RestController` method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{decisionId}/decisions", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public List<DecisionResponse> getChildDecisions(@PathVariable Long decisionId, @Valid @RequestBody Direction direction) {
    }
```

I use enum `org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Direction` as a request body.

Right now the Spring internal logic unable to deserialize this `Direction` enum after request from client.

Could you please show how to write a custom enum converter(or something like that) and configure it with Spring Boot in order to be able to deserialize `Direction` enum from client request ? Also `null` value should be allowed.

Comment: Could you please post an example of request message ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should create custom converter class, that implements `HttpMessageConverter<T>` interface:

```
package com.somepackage;

public class DirectionConverter implements HttpMessageConverter<Sort.Direction> {

    public boolean canRead(Class<?> aClass, MediaType mediaType) {
        return aClass== Sort.Direction.class;
    }

    public boolean canWrite(Class<?> aClass, MediaType mediaType) {
        return false;
    }

    public List<MediaType> getSupportedMediaTypes() {
        return new LinkedList<MediaType>();
    }

    public Sort.Direction read(Class<? extends Sort.Direction> aClass,
                                 HttpInputMessage httpInputMessage) 
                                 throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {   

        String string = IOUtils.toString(httpInputMessage.getBody(), "UTF-8");
        //here do any convertions and return result 
    }

    public void write(Sort.Direction value, MediaType mediaType, 
                      HttpOutputMessage httpOutputMessage) 
                      throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {

    }

}
```

I used `IOUtils` from [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) for convert `InputStream` to `String`. But you can do it any preferred way.

Now you have register created converter in Spring converters list. Add into `<mvc:annotation-driven>` tag next:

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven>
     <mvc:message-converters>
         <bean class="com.somepackage.DirectionConverter"/>
     </mvc:message-converters>
 </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Or if you're using java config:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(
      List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {    
        messageConverters.add(new DirectionConverter()); 
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
}
```